# What is chef attribute precedence

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

I have a default_attribute (eg :port) defined in environment file.
When I define the same attribute in my role, I am expecting chef to pick up the attribute from Role file. But its not happening.

eg, value of "port" in environment file = 8080
eg, value of "port" in role file = 9090.

I am expecting value of port to be 9090 but actually it is coming as 8080.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: In addition to adding the code for the role and environment, make sure you've updated them to the Chef Server.

Comment: yes role should precede environment , are you sure that you are using that role in your run list, and also make sure attributes are updated.

Comment: I have uploaded the role to chef server and then I am bootstrapping my node with this role. Do I need to do anything else as well?
I have mentioned my "default_attributes" after "run_list" in my role

Comment: Sample role json file-

{
  "name": "myrole",
  "description": "Manages myrole for NON Prod",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[tomcat]",
    "recipe[java]"
  ],
  "default_attributes": {
  "catalina_opts": [
    "-DXXXX",
   "-DYYY",
   "-DZZZ"
   ]
  }
}

Comment: Have tried testing while removing port variable from environment and see what happens. I suspect role is not properly assigned.